# Array that prints something every two columns

Tags: java

I know that I can do

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
```

Can I make an array that prints something every two columns? The following is wrong.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i+2) {
```

or

```
int k=2

for(int i=0; i<5; i+k){
```

Comment: `i++` is a shortcut for `i = i + 1` or `i += 1`, so simply use `i = i + 2` or `i += 2`.

Comment: This is not an array, but a for-loop.

Comment: This you use it when you fill arrays, and I was confused. Anyway, and thanks for you answers!!! They were correct!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is an example for you:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String example[] = { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3",
                "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 7",
                "item 8", "item 9", "item 10" };
        for (int i = 0; i < example.length; i += 2) {
            System.out.println(example[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
item 1
item 3
item 5
item 7
item 9
```

Comment: You are not explaining the error OP is making. Merely dumping example code is not a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot `=` in your `i+=2` statement. `i+2` is just an expression that doesn't change original value of `i`. `i+=2` or `i=i+2` does.

How about this?

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i+=2){}
```

Comment: A little more description would be helpful here

Comment: It seems you forgot "=" in your i+=2 statement. i+2 is just an expression that doesn't change original value of i, i+=2 or i=i+2 does

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i += 2){
```

This will increase the value of i by 2. "i+2" at that point is simply a syntax error and won't compile.

Also, this is not about arrays. This is a `for`-loop. An array is a data structure.
Some useful links:
The official Java tutorial about [for-loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).
The official Java tutorial about [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: *"'i+2' at that point is simply a syntax error and won't compile."* This statement is false. It is syntactically correct and **will** compile. It is however, a **semantic error** or a **logic error** - it will result in an infinite loop since the value of `i` never changes (unless the body of the loop change its value).

Comment: @ADTC I tried it on ideone.com, which says it uses sun-jdk-1.7.0-25 . It responds with a compilation error: "Main.java:14: error: not a statement" "for(int i=0; i<5; i + 2){" .

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right, I apologize. It gives a compilation error. In any case, we could put a statement there that properly compiles but still doesn't change the value of `i` in a way that the check `i<5` fails, for example: `i=2`

Comment: Apology accepted. It would actually have been interesting if you had been right.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is very unclear from your question what you are looking for!
If I get it correct, you want to print array items skipping one item. If so, may be your are printing loop index, not array items.

```
        int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i=i+2){
```